# Which institutions in Canada offer true read-only guest accounts?

Tags: canada, online-banking, security, mint.com

I've been reading a lot about Mint.com and Yodlee, but I just can't get over the fact that they store a set of credentials which could be used to empty your bank account if they fell into the wrong hands.

These aggregators would be far safer if there was a way to access your banking data using a separate set of credentials that provide read-only access. I've already heard that, in the U.S., Wells Fargo and ING Direct offer this kind of service via [guest users](https://www.wellsfargo.com/biz/online_banking/faq#Q14) and  [personal finance access codes](http://helpcenter.ingdirect.com/ingd/Topic.aspx?category=FINANCE1#PFAC1), respectively.

So, which financial institutions in Canada offer this service?

Comment: Perhaps you should tag this with the country you're specifically interested in?  It would make the question more useful to others, too, since banking options are typically region-specific.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I've tagged the question to indicate that I'm interested in Canadian institutions.

Comment: I don't think any Canadian bank offers this capability for online banking. However, there seems to be a fierce push right now at most banks to improve their online banking platform so they may be open to the suggestion of guest accounts.

Answer (score 3):

Converting fideli comment to answer

I don't think any Canadian bank offers this capability for online banking. However, there seems to be a fierce push right now at most banks to improve their online banking platform so they may be open to the suggestion of guest accounts